# Database view performance issue versus underlying query

Tags: mysql, database, performance, sql-execution-plan, database-view

I'm noticing a difference in performance between a View and the underlying Select statement that produces that view.

When the View is created, it does a table scan across all of the underlying tables (some 7 million rows), but the Select statement does not do such a scan.

Can someone explain why there might be a difference? And how I could make the View perform like the Select statement?

Explain Plan of both queries can be found in a Google Sheet: [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQh2cVsx8Rz6wH9DIIrqek7vzQM7QV4B7mZjnFrZRrxpRQ5hhXd2GMD3680dxkEZLUfGEKGLGXKgV8U/pubhtml)

Select statement:
UPDATE: I've narrowed down the problem to the following Select statement. It looks like the Group By or the Group Concat might be causing the issue.

```
SELECT
    -- IOHD_REQUEST fields
    r.ID as requestIdMultiple
    -- KEYVALUE and MULTIPLE fields
    , CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(kv6.VALUE)AS CHAR(255)) AS CLIENT_ID
    , CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(kv1.VALUE) AS CHAR(255)) AS IDENTIFIER_ID
    , CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(ri.IDENTIFIER) AS CHAR(255)) AS IDENTIFIER
    , CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(kv7.VALUE) AS CHAR(255)) AS PLATFORM_ID
    , CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(kv8.VALUE) AS CHAR(255)) AS VENDOR_ID

FROM IOHD_REQUEST r
 LEFT JOIN IOHD_REQUEST_HELPDESK rh ON r.ID = rh.REQUEST_ID
 LEFT JOIN IOHD_REQUEST_CLIENT rc ON r.ID = rc.REQUEST_ID
 LEFT JOIN IOHD_REQUEST_IDENTIFIER ri ON r.ID = ri.REQUEST_ID
 LEFT JOIN IOHD_REQUEST_PLATFORM rp ON r.ID = rp.REQUEST_ID
 LEFT JOIN IOHD_REQUEST_VENDOR rv ON r.ID = rv.REQUEST_ID
 LEFT JOIN IOHD_REF_KEYVALUE kv1 ON (ri.IDENTIFIER_ID = kv1.KEY AND kv1.TYPE = 'IDENTIFIERTYPE')
 LEFT JOIN IOHD_REF_KEYVALUE kv6 ON (rc.CLIENT_ID = kv6.KEY AND kv6.TYPE = 'CLIENT')
 LEFT JOIN IOHD_REF_KEYVALUE kv7 ON (rp.PLATFORM_ID = kv7.KEY AND kv7.TYPE = 'PLATFORM')
 LEFT JOIN IOHD_REF_KEYVALUE kv8 ON (rv.VENDOR_ID = kv8.KEY AND kv8.TYPE = 'VENDOR')
GROUP BY r.ID;
```

The line that's throwing me off in the view's explain plan is below. All subsequent rows in the plan are identical between the view and the select statement:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    7237546 100 NULL
```

Indices

```
--
-- Indexes for table `IOHD_REF_KEYVALUE`
--
ALTER TABLE `IOHD_REF_KEYVALUE`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD KEY `TYPE` (`TYPE`,`KEY`);

--
-- Indexes for table `IOHD_REQUEST`
--
ALTER TABLE `IOHD_REQUEST`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);

--
-- Indexes for table `IOHD_REQUEST_CLIENT`
--
ALTER TABLE `IOHD_REQUEST_CLIENT`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD KEY `REQUEST_ID` (`REQUEST_ID`);

--
-- Indexes for table `IOHD_REQUEST_HELPDESK`
--
ALTER TABLE `IOHD_REQUEST_HELPDESK`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD KEY `REQUEST_ID` (`REQUEST_ID`);

--
-- Indexes for table `IOHD_REQUEST_IDENTIFIER`
--
ALTER TABLE `IOHD_REQUEST_IDENTIFIER`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD KEY `REQUEST_ID` (`REQUEST_ID`);

--
-- Indexes for table `IOHD_REQUEST_PLATFORM`
--
ALTER TABLE `IOHD_REQUEST_PLATFORM`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD KEY `REQUEST_ID` (`REQUEST_ID`);

--
-- Indexes for table `IOHD_REQUEST_VENDOR`
--
ALTER TABLE `IOHD_REQUEST_VENDOR`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD KEY `REQUEST_ID` (`REQUEST_ID`);
```

Comment: Can you include the actual code for the view and select, if possible?  This sounds off to me; a view's performance should totally depend on the underlying query (unless perhaps it is a materialized view).

Comment: Also the Google sheet is broken for me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen updated!

Comment: Do you have indices setup to make the joins faster?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes - all indices have now been provided.

Comment: Update: I didn't figure out why I was seeing different EXPLAIN results for the View versus the Select statement, but I did identify why performance was so poor. It had to do with the LEFT JOIN against a series of tables, each with 50k rows. The join was taking every possible combination (e.g. 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 | 1, 1, 1, 1, 2 ...) before grouping the results.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, the problems of key-value schemas.  Aside from abandoning the design pattern, let's look at improving the indexes.

`IOHD_REF_KEYVALUE` desperately needs help.

- `PRIMARY KEY(TYPE, KEY)`  -- (the opposite order is ok)
- Get rid of `id` completely.
- Table must be InnoDB.
- See also http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

There is an "explode-implode" going on.  That is `JOIN` leads to more rows; `GROUP BY` brings it back down.  Meanwhile a huge tmp table is built.  A partial cure is to replace

```
CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(kv6.VALUE)AS CHAR(255)) AS CLIENT_ID
and
LEFT JOIN IOHD_REF_KEYVALUE kv6 ON (rc.CLIENT_ID = kv6.KEY AND kv6.TYPE = 'CLIENT')
```

with

```
( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(VALUE)
      FROM IOHD_REF_KEYVALUE
      WHERE KEY = rc.CLIENT_ID
        AND TYPE = 'CLIENT'
) AS CLIENT_ID
```

(Ditto for similar cases.)

After you have fixed what you can, come back for more help, but be sure to bring `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`